# What action/filter can be used for modifying the page to be rendered?

Tags: filters, actions, page-template

Let's say there's a template file called `sample-template.php` with contents below

### sample-template.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Sample template
 **/
get_header(); ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<myplugin type="video" id="1"></myplugin>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

and is expected to be rendered by wordpress like so

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><title>The Title</title></head>
    <body>
        <h1>The Title</h1>
        <myplugin type="video" id="1"></myplugin>
    </body>
</html>
```

but before it gets rendered by wordpress, I want to replace `<myplugin type="video" id="1"></myplugin>` with a different string

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><title>The Title</title></head>
    <body>
        <h1>The Title</h1>
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/hxnb2V0muGw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

such that `<myplugin type="video" id="1"></myplugin>` wil be replaced by `<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/hxnb2V0muGw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

What action or filter can be used for modifying the page to be rendered?

Comment: You can't modify HTML with PHP unless it is output by PHP. You could use JavaScript to edit the element once it is loaded though. Is a JavaScript solution possible for you to use? Why aren't you able to just change the template directly?

Comment: @RichardWebster The intent here is to be able to change the string right from the server-side. Thus, JavaScript on this case is not a viable option. The reason why just-changing-the-template-directly is not an option is that I wanted also to implement `<myplugin type="breadcrumb" />` which will generate the page link heirarchy

Comment: So if you removed that HTML entirely and had your own action you could hook into with an add_action() call, would that be useful to you? You could then output as many elements as you'd like. Or failing adding your own, you could hook into the the_title() action call and output stuff after the title. I can give you some code if you answer those. Otherwise you can't change hardcoded HTML directly with PHP.

Comment: agree with @RichardWebster, using `<?php do_action('my-plugin'); ?>` in the template is the most flexible solution here, then you can add actions to that hook that can do any infinite number of things.